# Pytest doesnt find file out of the test folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to create a test at pytest using moto to upload a Cloud Formation to AWS using boto3.

The test I'm doing is this one:

```
def test_main_success(self, cf):
    'Test upload with a new stack'
    sys.stdout = mystdout = io.StringIO()
    expected_return = (
                    "Criando teste\n"
                    "...aguardando resposta da aws...\n"
                    "Sucesso\n"
                    )

    main(["teste", "teste.yaml"])
    content = mystdout.getvalue()
    assert content == expected_return
```

The problem is that it doesn't find the file.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './resources/teste.yaml'
```

But the file is there and when I try the script it runs just fine, and gets the file.

The file where it's trying to get is in the folder of the script not the folder of the test

```
├── cl_uploader
│   ├── cl_uploader.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── resources
│       ├── 1-ec2-with-sg-eip.yaml
│       └── teste.yaml
└── tests
    ├── resources
    │   └── teste.yaml
    └── test_cl_uploader.py
```

The pytest don't get files out of the folder where the test is?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a

```
__init__.py
```

in your tests folder

your repository should have be as follow:

````
├── cl_uploader
│   ├── cl_uploader.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── resources
│       ├── 1-ec2-with-sg-eip.yaml
│       └── teste.yaml
└── tests
    ├── resources
    │   └── teste.yaml
    ├── __init__.py # init here ! :)
    └── test_cl_uploader.py```
````

verify that you pytest configuration file (aka pytest.ini) define [discovery strateg](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions)y for the same pattern

Comment: can you had your pytest configuration file ?

Comment: I'm using poetry. Só when I run my pytest it gets the path from the root folder. Só I changed the the folder Name to os.path.dirname(__file__) and worked.